# Python "smart" regex substitution based on the match it self?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to conduct a "smart" regex substitution. For example, consider:

```
import re
str = "x(x) and y(y)"
res = re.sub("\(.*?\)","z", str)
```

The result is:

```
xz and yz
```

So essentially when the regex `"\(.*?\)"` finds a match `m` that match is replaced with `"z"`. However, I would like to replace the match `m` with some function of itself: `f(m)`:

```
import re
str = "x(x) and y(y)"
res = re.sub("\(.*?\)",lambda m: m[:-1] + ", z" + m[-1], str)
```

which should yield:

```
x(x, z) and y(y, z)
```

Is there a python/elegant way to do this?

Comment: (Side remark: don't use `str` as a variable name in Python code.)

Comment: @stribizhev please check Maroun Maroun's answer he's hit the nail on the head!

Comment: @ajcr you are right, I followed the tutorial here: http://www.python-course.eu/re_advanced.php, and for some reason they used str.

Comment: I notice that course also uses `sum` as a variable name in [another lesson](http://www.python-course.eu/for_loop.php). The author needs a very stern talking to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the match and:

```
res = re.sub("\((.*?)\)", "(\g<1>, z)",  str)
```

`\g<1>` contains the matched group (in this case it's what's inside the parenthesis in the equation).

---

```
>>> str = "x(x) and y(y)"
>>> res = re.sub("\((.*?)\)", "(\g<1>, z)",  str)
>>> res
'x(x, z) and y(y, z)'
```

<sup>I recommend you to avoid using variable names that has meaning in Python, like `str`, `list`.. User `s` for example for string.</sup>

### [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Let's take a look at the following regex:

```
(\d+)([a-z]+)
```

The regex matches one or more digit, followed by one or more character in the range "a-z". Given the string "1234helloWorld", the first group (`\1`) matches the digits, the second group matches the [a-z] chars.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. Where do I learn about the syntax you used here `"(\g<1>, z)"`?

Comment: @applecider: `\g<1>` is just an unambiguous back-reference to the first capture group (what is captured by the subpattern inside unescaped `(...)`). You can read about it in the [`re.sub` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: @Maroun Maroun, ahh got it! So if I had two `.*?` then `\g<1>` would give me the 1st capture, and `\g<2>` would give me the 2nd capture?

Comment: @applecider I added an explanation.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun thanks a ton! This is exactly what I needed, need to wait 1 more min before accepting.

Comment: @applecider I'm glad it helped you. As stribizhev already mentioned, I really recommend you to visit the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) module.

Comment: Although this answer neatly solves the OP test example, it does not describe the much more powerful and flexible method of using a function as the replacement argument (as described in the `sub()` documentation).